# Strip any unknown characters from string php

Tags: php

I have a restful web service, that gets input string, sanitizes it and saves it to MySQL database.

My workflow looks like this:
I get string, I trim it. Then I remove any non alphanumeric characters, leaving underscore. And then I replace underscore with space. And then I save it to database.

```
    $trimmedName = trim($name);
    $replacedName = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z_]/", "", $trimmedName);
    $sanitizedName = trim(str_replace("_", " ", $replacedName));
```

Problem is, that this works fine 99% of time. But sometimes, I see in database that there is a square symbol. I dont have photo of that, but you get the idea. Im not sure what it is and why my preg_replace does not strip it out. I think someone tries to take advantage of this bug, so I would like to know what is wrong with my regex, why it leaves some unknown characters.

Comment: What is your database character set encoding ?

Comment: Not related, but `trim` is redundant since `preg_replace` will remove all the spaces.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your preg_replace. Your problem is probably in code you haven't looked at yet: Maybe some other process insert data without you knowing it. Maybe your sanitation routine is skipped in some context. Maybe another component adds corrupt data to what you have sanitized. Keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably as a result of the characters you are saving. The names have some accent on some letters. This means you check your character encoding and set it to UTF-8 in the code header.

**PHP**

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Also make sure your database table's character set is UTF-8

You can update the table **MySQL**

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: I tried to echo that string to my slack channel, and I see that instead of that character it prints underscore _. So I guess that character is unknown not also in my MySQL database. I wonder if
$isUTF8 = preg_match('//u', $name);
this check would help to detect if that string has some unknown characters?